# Restricting Access to All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, bestpractice, data-designer, populations

For compliance reasons, we need to restrict our user's access to All Subscribers but still allow them the ability to look up activity and engagement information for specific contacts. We use the multi org connector so we need to restrict their view to contacts only within their Business Unit.

Can I create a population for each Business Unit's contacts in Data Designer, and restrict their access to All Subscribers in roles? I want them to see contact-specific engagement and activity, but only for contacts in their business unit.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: can you not restrict All subs in BU level?

Comment: I can't because we don't make use of Profile Attributes in a uniform way across all business units, so I can't apply a Subscriber Filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Role if you have Administrative privileges. In the Permissions section click the "deny" checkbox to `View Subscribers` under `All Subscribers'. Edit the individual Permissions to as you see fits.

[image: Roles and Permissions]